# Cmake: Create directory command in suddirectory's CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: cmake, build-process

I have included a subdirectory in root's CMakeLists.txt with explicitly specifying the `binary_dir` as follow

`add_subdirectory(subdir_with_CMakeLists.txt out_dir)`

all the target are built into the `out_dir` as it supposed to, however **MAKE_DIRECTORY** command - `file(MAKE_DIRECTORY some_dir)` inside the included CMakeLists.txt creates the directory relative to the location of subdirectory's CMakeLists.txt, not inside the `out_dir` as I expected.

Now, Is there a way to **create a directory relative to the `binary_dir` specified in `add_subdirecoty` command?**.

**Note**: The included subdirectory is a portable module so directory creation command should reside in its CMakeLists.txt file, not inside the root's CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's [CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR) variable. You may use it in expressions in CMake commands

Comment: Thank you, it worked! --> `file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/some_dir)`